# I would like to delete this question of mine, community deletion.

Tags: support, specific-question, deletion

I would like to delete this embarassing older question of mine:

[$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=L$, definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399053/lim-x-to-infty-fx-l-definition)

But I can not delete it, since it has an answer and I do not have 10.000 reputation (I guess).

I would like to request a 'community deletion', if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Since I don't see much value in keeping that linked question (or its answer) around, plus you're asking to have it removed, I have just given the second vote to delete. I believe it should require just one more vote for it to be deleted.

Comment: If this is due to the negative votes to your post that you want to have it deleted, it is quite unfortunate. You could have written the post in a way that may benefit other readers since it has an answer already. Not everyone has an access to a clear definition of $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=L$ when the concept of limits are taught. If you phrased it as a `reference-request` question, it would be better received I believe.

Comment: Success – the question has been deleted (I note, though, that there's currently one vote to undelete).